# How I can push Parse Objects into an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, parse-platform

I need use an array of `Parse.User` objectId's from Parse Platform to fetch this users and save a Parse Object called 'Project' with a column 'Gestor' that have the users who are managers of the project saved.

That is my array:

```
data.gestor = [
  "riid9e82uA",
  "tYxICE1ZOf",
  "MXYSc0iiYK"
]
```

There is my function:

```
let gestors = [];
await data.gestor.forEach(async (value) => {
    console.log(value);
    let userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    userQuery.equalTo('objectId', value);
    let newGestor = await userQuery.first();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(newGestor, null, 2));
    await gestors.push(newGestor);
})
console.log(JSON.stringify(gestors, null, 2));
```

On the console output I have the Id's, after the code first print the array gestors empty, so I have the objects that I print on console.log() into forEach:

```
riid9e82uA
aw6cjLgajN
tYxICE1ZOf
[]
{
  "username": "teste123@email.com",
  "firstName": "ola",
  "lastName": "adeus",
  "emailVerified": false,
.
.
.
"tYxICE1ZOf": {
      "read": true,
      "write": true
    }
  },
  "objectId": "tYxICE1ZOf"
}
```

Why the code executes first the third `console.log()` before the second into the forEach and how I can push the objects into an array and after use this array correctly populated to create my new Object?

Answer (score 0):

Usage of async/await inside forEach is a little bit tricky.

You can create your own **forEach** function:

```
async function asyncForEach(array, callback) {
  for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    await callback(array[index], index, array);
  }
}
```

Then you can adjust your code:

```
let gestors = [];
await asyncForEach(data.gestor, async (value) => {
    console.log(value);
    let userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    userQuery.equalTo('objectId', value);
    let newGestor = await userQuery.first();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(newGestor, null, 2));
    await gestors.push(newGestor);
})
console.log(JSON.stringify(gestors, null, 2));
```

Source: https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404

Let me know if it works!

Comment: Yeah, I solved creating another function do to the loop, but using for...of like I showed on my answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Worked pretty well the answer on [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop) using `for ... of` like that:

```
let gestors = [];
async function getGestors (gestores) {
    for (const gestor of gestores) {
       let userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
       userQuery.equalTo('objectId', gestor);
       let newGestor = await userQuery.first();
       gestors.push(newGestor);
    }
}
await getGestors(data.gestor);
console.log(JSON.stringify(gestors, null, 2));
```

Now I have the output as expected and I am saving correctly an array of Parse.User on my new Object.

Should I keep this topic or remove because another topic has the solution?